# Collapsable menu bar

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking for a collapsable menu bar (like Foundation or Bootstrap).

I don't need any other components except for the menu bar. I know I could download custom components, but I would rather learn how to make one from scratch so I can understand how they work a bit better.

Does anyone know of any tutorials on how to make one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct link to a great document. Very informative ...

### http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/

It does not provide any CSS, but you can inspect certain elements (f12 or right-click : inspect element) and discover their CSS properties, and then try it for yourself.

There is a lot of information in there and it can be a bit overwhelming. Especially with all of the code that they provide. Try to read it slowly, because it really includes all of the information that you need to make a navbar, especially a navbar that is up to your standards.

Another pretty good link is here :

### http://jqbox.webflow.com/

Shows you everything, including JQuery code. If you want the CSS same case, but because it isn't bootstrap you can get the physical CSS with the same inspect element feature or for a direct link to the stylesheet -- http://jqbox.webflow.com/jqbox.webflow.css

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking at bootstrap and foundation, and did inspect their code a bit, but I was really curious how to build the jquery for the menu after collapse. My current menu can collapse, but function a little oddly on touch devices after collapse, especially with sub menu items

Comment: @Quoid would love to help you there, unfortunately I don't have very much experience with mobile. It is also hard to say what the issue is without seeing it.

Answer (score -1):

Without providing a direct link to one, you may try using media queries.

For instance:

```
    /*NAV BAR*/
    #nav { display: block}
    #mobile-nav { display: hidden;}

   @media screen and (max-width:320px) { 

     #mobile-nav { display: block;} 
     #nav { display: hidden;}

    }
```

Team Treehouse has a pretty good blog post about creating purely CSS mobile menus. My only issue with pure CSS menus like theirs is that if you follow their instructions, opening the menu will require you to click a menu option to get rid of the menu -- there's no close button and you can't close by clicking the body of the page.

A JS implementation would *probably* include something like

```
    $('.rmm').each(function() {
        var $width = $(this).css('max-width');
        $width = $width.replace('px', ''); 
        if ( $(this).parent().width() < $width*1.05 ) {
            $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').hide(0);
            $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').show(0);
        }
        else {
            $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').show(0);
            $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').hide(0);
        }
    });
```

}

this function from [here](http://responsivemobilemenu.com/en/) resizes the menu based on a predefined width in your CSS.

The best "tutorial" I found was literally stealing someone else's code for my site and then tweaking it until it didn't look like theirs. The links that metsales provided are excellent as well.